# Label nonzero neighbour values in 2d array

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I have a 2d list consist of 0 and 1 like this

```py
a=[['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
   ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
   ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
   ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
   ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

I want to group '**1**'  that are near each others in every direction and replace them with a group number like this

```py
a=[['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
   ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '3'],
   ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
   ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
   ['0', '5', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is known as connected component labeling, and you have scipy's [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) for that:

```
from scipy import ndimage 
import numpy as np

a = np.array(l, dtype=('i1'))
x_components, _ = ndimage.measurements.label(a, np.ones((3, 3)))

array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```